# Pandas: No column names in data file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I am trying to process a dataset to play with for DataScience but it does not have column names. The output of `df.head()` as shown below:

```
   1  73                  Not in universe   0  0.1   0.2  Not in universe.1
0  2  58   Self-employed-not incorporated   4   34     0    Not in universe
1  3  18                  Not in universe   0    0     0        High school
2  4   9                  Not in universe   0    0     0    Not in universe
3  5  10                  Not in universe   0    0     0    Not in universe
4  6  48                          Private  40   10  1200    Not in universe
```

What I would like to see is

```
0  1  73                  Not in universe   0  0.1   0.2  Not in universe.1
1  2  58   Self-employed-not incorporated   4   34     0    Not in universe
2  3  18                  Not in universe   0    0     0        High school
3  4   9                  Not in universe   0    0     0    Not in universe
4  5  10                  Not in universe   0    0     0    Not in universe
5  6  48                          Private  40   10  1200    Not in universe
```

I could assign random column names but is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You loaded the file without specifying whether it had a header row or not, by default it infers it from the first row, if it's missing then pass `header=None`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to go through [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Default value for header is 'infer' which means it will automatically set the integer values for the data if not specify.

Also you can set the different column names by setting names parameter which takes an array, list of column names.